# How to optimize the sql while running it on sql server

Tags: sql-server

How to optimize the same code sql below:

```
Declare @i int=0;
while @i<10000
Begin
Set @i=@i+1;
set @ID=(Select top(1) ID from Products.dbo.TempID where IsUpdate=0);
Delete from Attributes where ID=@ID;
Delete from Products where ID=@ID
Delete from Attributes_Archive where ID=@ID
update TempID set IsUpdate=1 where ID=@ID
end
```

Comment: Tell us what you've tried so far.

Comment: the same query, I was tried. but it was taking time while executing.

Answer (score 2):

Use set based queries instead of loops. In that case the whole query will be executed just once instead of your implementation where it is executed 10000 tiumes. Something like:

```
DELETE  FROM Attributes
WHERE   ID IN ( SELECT  ID
                FROM    Products.dbo.TempID
                WHERE   IsUpdate = 0
                        AND ID < 10000 );
DELETE  FROM Products
WHERE   ID IN ( SELECT  ID
                FROM    Products.dbo.TempID
                WHERE   IsUpdate = 0
                        AND ID < 10000 );
DELETE  FROM Attributes_Archive
WHERE   ID IN ( SELECT  ID
                FROM    Products.dbo.TempID
                WHERE   IsUpdate = 0
                        AND ID < 10000 );
UPDATE  TempID
SET     IsUpdate = 1
WHERE   ID IN ( SELECT  ID
                FROM    Products.dbo.TempID
                WHERE   IsUpdate = 0
                        AND ID < 10000 );
```

Or you can get the ID you want to delete/update first and then work with this list, something like that:

```
SELECT  ID
INTO    #ids
FROM    Products.dbo.TempID
WHERE   IsUpdate = 0
        AND id < 10000;

DELETE  FROM Attributes
WHERE   ID IN ( SELECT  ID
                FROM    #ids );
...
```